# Populating a "p" tag in HTML with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant figure out the syntax for this iv browsed the net when i mention "P" it returns multiple searches regarding PHP

What i want to do is populate a p tag text with a variable value?

This is my Jquery

```
$('.FOS, .MF, .CW, .OO, .LL, .CO, .TAK, .FCS, .CO').mouseover(function(e) {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var Comments = tr.find('.GeneralComments').text();
    if (Comments != "") {
        $('div#pop-up').show();
        $('p').text == Comments;
    } else {
        $('div#pop-up').hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Im trying to assign the value from Comments to the p.text but its not working?

Heres my div where the p take is situated.

```
<div id="pop-up">
        <h3>
            Over all Notes</h3>
        <p>
           This is where i want the value from comments to appear? 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Look at jQuery's documentation for `text()` to learn how to use that method.

Comment: You have includes the class "CO" twice in your very first selector

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will fill the paragraph tag inside `#pop-up` with the text inside the `Comments` variable

```
$("#pop-up > p").text(Comments);
```

I suggest you have a read of the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: @ScottAtkinson No problem mate, good luck with the rest of your site :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax.

```
$("#pop-up > p").text(Comments);
```

Best way is to add ID for that p tag. and use ID to populate comments, like add id `comments` to that p tag and you can use:

```
$("p#comments").text(Comments);
```

Comment: Expecting that OP can take care of that. Your answer will populate all p tags, which are children of pop-up ID.

Comment: Best way is to add ID for that p tag. and use ID to populate comments.

Comment: @Sam are you aware of OP's whole page ? or are you sure there will be no more such changes in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Comments != "") {
    $('div#pop-up').show();
    $('p').text(Comments);
}
```

== is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator.

Also in jQuery, you pass the assignment you want to make into the function as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Comments != "") {
    $('div#pop-up')
      .show()
      .find('p')
      .text(Comments);
}
```

See [docs for the `.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).